# How to use form to control unwanted data and user verification that goes into sql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, php-5.6

I'm new to Php and Mysql and this is my first project on it .Now I have  created  the sign up part of this project But I'm having some issues:

1.The errors I created don't seem to stop the unwanted data from going into the database.

2.If there is an error the whole form is wiped clean instead of some of the  information that is allowed to remain

3.I don't know the code to create an error for a check-box form type.

4. I don't Know a code that checks whether the username/ email is already taken .. although they are both already UNIQUE in Mysql.

Below is some part of my code ...ANY form of advice would be appreciated Thanks

```
  <?php


 // define variables and set to empty values
            $username="";
            $password="";
            $email="";
            $agreement="";
            $nameErr="";
            $passErr="";
            $emailErr="";
            $emailErr1="";
            $emailErr2="";
            $cboxErr="";

  function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;

  }         

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
      $nameErr = "Username is required";
   } else {
     $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
                  // check if name only contains numbers letters and some special   characters
             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/",$username)) {
             $nameErr = "Only letters , numbers , '@' , '_' allowed"; 
           }
   }
   if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
   $passErr = ' Password is required !';
   } else {
   $password = test_input($_POST['password']);

   if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9@_]*$/', $password)) {
          $passErr = 'password can only contain a upper/lower case letters ,             numbers, "_""@"';
} 
 } 

 if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
 $emailErr = "Email is required";
 } else {
 $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

 // check if e-mail address is well-formed
 if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["re-email"])) {
     $emailErr1 = "Please re-enter the email";
  } 
  else if ($_POST["email"] != $_POST["re-email"]){
      $emailErr2 = "The emails you entered do not match"; 
  }
  else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["re-email"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["agreement"])) {
      $tickErr = "Tick the box below ";
  } 
  else {
      $agreement = test_input($_POST["agreement"]);
  }
  }




 ?>

 <?php
    $msg="";
    require('connect.php');

    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string( $username);
    $email= mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password= mysql_real_escape_string($password);

      $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email) VALUES           ('$username', '$password', '$email')";

      $result = mysql_query($query);

      if($result){

        $msg = "User Created Successfully.";

         }
       }

   ?>
```

And here is the HTML PHP SIGN IN  FORM :

```
 <title> Feedool</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class = "header-menu">
 <div class ="pull-left">
 <ul>
 <li><a class="navigation" id = "home"  href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a class="navigation" id = "tournaments"       href="tournaments.html">Tournaments</a></li>
 <li><a class="navigation" id = "rules" href="rules.html">Rules</a></li>
 <li><a class="navigation" id = "faqs" href="index.html">FAQS</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class = "pull-right">
 <ul>
 <li> <a class="navigation" id = "login" href="login.php">Log In </a></li>
 <li><a class="navigation"  id = "signup" href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class = "logo-header">
 <a href = "index.html"><img src = "images/logo.png" ></a>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-4">
 </div>
 <div class = "col-4">
 <div class = "login">
 <div class = "header">

 <center><h1>Sign Up</h1></center>
 </div>




<form class = "sign-up"id= "sign-up " action= "<?php echo   htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">

<span class = "error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<input class="formfield" textarea class="detail-box" type="text"   id="username" name="username" size="40" placeholder="Username"/></center></p>
<span class = "error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<input class="formfield" textarea class="detail-box" type="email" id="email"  name="email" size="40" maxlength = '25' placeholder="Email"/></center></p>
<span class = "error"><?php echo $emailErr1;?></span><span class = "error"> <?php echo $emailErr2;?></span>
<input class="formfield" textarea class="detail-box" type="email" id="re-email" name="re-email" size="40" maxlength = '25' placeholder=" Re-type Email"/></center></p>
<span class = "error"><?php echo $passErr;?></span>
<input class="formfield" textarea class="detail-box" type="password" id="password" name="password" size="40" maxlength = '25' placeholder="Password"/></center></p>
<span class = "error"><?php echo $cboxErr;?></span>
<input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="agreement" class="tick">I AM OVER 18 YEARS OF AGE AND I AGREE TO THE <a href="terms.html">TERMS OF USE</a>



<div class = 'form-sub'>

<center><button class = 'btn-1' id = 'btn-1' type = 'button-1'>SignUp</button></center>
<center><p class = "word">
Join gamers from around the World!!! </p></center>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "col-4">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The errors I created don't seem to stop the unwanted data from going into the database.

I can't comment yet due to my rep, but what errors specifically?

> 2. If there is an error the whole form is wiped clean instead of some of the information that is allowed to remain

Probably best to take the values from the POST and `echo` the values into the `value` attributes for
        each input e.g.

```
<input class="formfield detail-box" type="text" id="username" name="username" size="40" placeholder="Username" value="<?php $_POST['username']; ?>"/></center></p>
```

> 3. I don't know the code to create an error for a check-box form type.

Try `$tickErr` in the error message, not `$cboxErr`;

```
  <span class="error"><?php echo $tickErr; ?></span>
```

> 4. I don't Know a code that checks whether the username/ email is already taken .. although they are both already UNIQUE in Mysql.

Try running a `SELECT` statement with the username/email given and reject the request if you get a result back from the query e.g.

```
SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?;
```

(with the `?` parameter being the posted username)

As an aside, you might want to research [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) (users maliciously editing the statement), your INSERT statement is susceptible to it. Also, consider encrypting passwords in the database.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.The errors I created don't seem to stop the unwanted data from going into the database.

You're not creating any errors. You're simply assigning error-strings to variables. Anywhere you've got an error, try something like `throw new Exception("Invalid email format");` instead of `$emailErr = "Invalid email format";`. Nothing is happening because you're not doing anything with `$emailErr`.

> 2.If there is an error the whole form is wiped clean instead of some of the information that is allowed to remain.

That's because the page is reloaded. You can re-populate the form after reload if you want, by doing something like this: `<input name='myinput' value='<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['myinput'])) echo $_REQUEST['myinput']; ?>' />`

> 3. I don't know the code to create an error for a check-box form type.

See #1

> 4. I don't Know a code that checks whether the username/ email is already taken .. although they are both already UNIQUE in Mysql.

You have to make another query to the database. Do a `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :un` first, then count the results.

the `mysql_` functions are deprecated and are not safe to use. Look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.